# My treeView populate a strange children : WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I constructed a treeView WPF MVVM with the help of this very good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode)
Then I created a contextMenu for some node that allowed me to add children from selected parent.

The problem is if I click on "Add" without expanding manually the selected node(parent), a strange child is created automatically in addition to the node expected to be generated when clicking on "Add".

I tried to detect the problem so I change the code below from:

```
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

to:

```
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
```

Image 1 below shows the result of this test or Image 2 shows what my treeView must show.

- **image1**
  [image]
- **image2**

[image]

Rq: I used image from the [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) that I talked about it. Also, I used the same approach described in the article (including the class TreeViewItemViewModel.cs )

- Base class for all ViewModel

  public class TreeViewItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      #region Data

  ```
  static readonly TreeViewItemViewModel DummyChild = new TreeViewItemViewModel();

  readonly ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> _children;
  readonly TreeViewItemViewModel _parent;

  bool _isExpanded;
  bool _isSelected;

  #endregion // Data

  #region Constructors

  protected TreeViewItemViewModel(TreeViewItemViewModel parent, bool lazyLoadChildren)
  {
      _parent = parent;

      _children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel>();

      if (lazyLoadChildren)
          _children.Add(DummyChild);
  }

  // This is used to create the DummyChild instance.
  private TreeViewItemViewModel()
  {
  }

  #endregion // Constructors

  #region Presentation Members

  #region Children

  /// <summary>
  /// Returns the logical child items of this object.
  /// </summary>
  public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> Children
  {
      get { return _children; }
  }

  #endregion // Children

  #region HasLoadedChildren

  /// <summary>
  /// Returns true if this object's Children have not yet been populated.
  /// </summary>
  public bool HasDummyChild
  {
      get { return this.Children.Count == 1 && this.Children[0] == DummyChild; }
  }

  #endregion // HasLoadedChildren

  #region IsExpanded

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets/sets whether the TreeViewItem 
  /// associated with this object is expanded.
  /// </summary>
  public bool IsExpanded
  {
      get { return _isExpanded; }
      set
      {
          if (value != _isExpanded)
          {
              _isExpanded = value;
              this.OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
          }

          // Expand all the way up to the root.
          if (_isExpanded && _parent != null)
              _parent.IsExpanded = true;

          // Lazy load the child items, if necessary.
          if (this.HasDummyChild)
          {
              this.Children.Remove(DummyChild);
              this.LoadChildren();
          }
      }
  }

  #endregion // IsExpanded

  #region IsSelected

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets/sets whether the TreeViewItem 
  /// associated with this object is selected.
  /// </summary>
  public bool IsSelected
  {
      get { return _isSelected; }
      set
      {
          if (value != _isSelected)
          {
              _isSelected = value;
              this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
          }
      }
  }

  #endregion // IsSelected

  #region LoadChildren

  /// <summary>
  /// Invoked when the child items need to be loaded on demand.
  /// Subclasses can override this to populate the Children collection.
  /// </summary>
  protected virtual void LoadChildren()
  {
  }

  #endregion // LoadChildren

  #region Parent

  public TreeViewItemViewModel Parent
  {
      get { return _parent; }
  }

  #endregion // Parent

  #endregion // Presentation Members

  #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
      if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
          this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members
  ```

  }
- Myxml:

`<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Regions}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnableTree}" >
      <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <!-- 
        This Style binds a TreeViewItem to a TreeViewItemViewModel. 
        -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
          <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
           <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
          <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <TreeView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="AddCity"  ItemsSource="{Binding AddCityItems}"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
          DataType="{x:Type local:StateViewModel}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
          >
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ContextMenu="{StaticResource AddCity}">
            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\Region.png" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RegionName}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.Resources>`

- RegionViewModel:

`public class StateViewModel : TreeViewItemViewModel
    {

```
   readonly State _state;
   public ICommand AddCityCommand { get; private set; }
   public List<MenuItem> AddCityItems { get; set; }

    public StateViewModel(State state, RegionViewModel parentRegion)
        : base(parentRegion, true)
    {
        _state = state;
        AddCityItems = new List<MenuItem>();
        AddCityCommand = new DelegateCommand<CancelEventArgs>(OnAddCityCommandExecute, OnAddCityCommandCanExecute);
        AddCityItems.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Add City", Command = AddCityCommand });
    }

    public string StateName
    {
        get { return _state.StateName; }
    }

    protected override void LoadChildren()
    {
        foreach (City city in Database.GetCities(_state))
            base.Children.Add(new CityViewModel(city, this));
    }


    bool OnAddCityCommandCanExecute(CancelEventArgs parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnAddCityCommandExecute(CancelEventArgs parameter)
    {
        var myNewCity = new city();
        Children.Add(new CityViewModel(myNewCity, this));
    }
}`
```

BTW, if I expand my parent node then I click into add City, I have the result as expected but if I don't expand parent node and I click on contextMenu I have another child created in addition to the child I want to create

**EDIT**
I add the statemnt below to my add() method and I don't have any problem now:

```
public void OnAddCityCommandExecute(CancelEventArgs parameter)
    {
        var myNewCity = new city();
        Children.Add(new CityViewModel(myNewCity, this));
        //the modif
        this.Children.Remove(DummyChild);
    }
```

Comment: And where's the code?

Comment: I can see you bind to the ViewModel object directly as your node display text in Image1. The output is simply the ViewModel.ToString(). We cannot help you until you put your xmal and ViewModel for review

Comment: @cscmh99, I gave you the article that I use it to create my TreeView. I used exactly the same code. So why should I put my code if we have all the source. !
Can you please explain more what did you mean by "I bind the ViewModel object directly" !

Comment: @EmpereurAiman you can open the article above

Comment: @SADOK You could post the minimum code for us to understand without reading a big article.. See : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok, I will do.
I thought that it will be more easier to open all project from article

Comment: Please don't be mad as i might've missed something in your question again. May I know where's the "ADD" logic you implemented ?

Comment: I said the problem appears even if I set isExpended to true. (I want to simplify the peoblem for the reader but if you wish I will put the code of Add)

Comment: Too bad that I cannot paste a screen dump over here. But I do play around the sample a bit and having  no problem adding node to the TreeList. I can add node to Region and State level without much problem (Well I did change the Regions Collection from CountryViewModel to ObservableColleciton). My best guess would be, you are adding wrong type of viewmodel to the Children list. You need to be aware of which level you're in and add the corresponding ViewModel to Children e.g. StateViewModel. Anyway, let's wait and see your add feature

Comment: On my way home so couldn't really test ur code but ... Can you check if the additional object u have is Dummychild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the bug in your code.

Here's the steps to reproduce:

1. At state node (never expand it first)
2. Without Expanding the Child upfront, Your StateViewModel's Children contain a DummyChild.
3. Added 1 new City into the list which cause the HasDummyChild won't work as the count is now 2 in Children's list
4. Then when you try to expand the node to check the result. Your treelist will have the DummyChild which is a base class that screwed up everything

So, basically that's why "Expand" first is the key of your problem as at that time HasDummyChild still working as it compares .Count == 1. The tree won't remove the DummyChild out from your Children list if you add an extra child to the list that makes .Count == 2.

ADDITIONAL INFO as requested

Just change the HasDummyChild as the following

```
    public bool HasDummyChild
    {
        //get { return this.Children.Count == 1 && this.Children[0] == DummyChild; }
        get { return Children.Any() && Children.Contains(DummyChild); }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I well understand what you say. but I know that you give me an idea that I implement it and I correct the pb (Just see the edit above) but I still want to know how didn't find problem when you play with the sample. Can you please edit your answer and put your code. (just the modification that you have added and I will try to test it in the project from article)

Comment: I cannot figure out why my answer couldn't explain what's happening but provide you a fix anyway.

Comment: Just to be sure you'll take this seriously, I actually migrated your code and reproduce your bug. So, read my description again trying to understand what I put in the answer

Comment: Oh ... I guess I didn't answer your question in comment. It's simply because I think having a DummyChild in Children upfront is so freaking nasty in my eyes and remove all those related code (it's just a habit). So I don't have the same problem like you did. Com'on ... I'm the only one who ever doubt your add node implementation and guess that there's an instance with wrong type being added to the list, don't you think that's for some reason ? =) .. anyway .. where's my score for an answer ??

Comment: You deserve also an upVote. I still have two other question about TreeView. I constrcuted all my nodes and Know I try to coorrect some bug like this question. So I will create another questions and I will suggest you.

Comment: No problem. Just let me know.